# Magento Custom Admin button url

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I created a button on my Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View file and i want it to point to my admin html controller but for an unknown reason when i click the button i got a page 404 error in the front end.

this is my /etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <PixelPlusOne_DragonPay>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </PixelPlusOne_DragonPay>>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <dragonpay>
        <class>PixelPlusOne_DragonPay_Model</class>
      </dragonpay>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <dragonpay>
        <class>PixelPlusOne_DragonPay_Helper</class>
      </dragonpay>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <dragonpay>
        <class>PixelPlusOne_DragonPay_Block</class>
      </dragonpay>
    </blocks>

  </global>
  <default>
    <payment>
      <dragonpay>
        <model>dragonpay/standard</model>
        <active>1</active>
        <order_status>pending</order_status>
        <title>Dragon Pay</title>
        <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
        <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
      </dragonpay>
    </payment>
  </default>
  <admin>
      <routers>
          <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
              <args>
                  <modules>
                      <PixelPlusOne_DragonPay before="Mage_Adminhtml">PixelPlusOne_DragonPay_Adminhtml</PixelPlusOne_DragonPay>
                  </modules>
              </args>
          </adminhtml>
      </routers>
  </admin>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <dragonpay>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>PixelPlusOne_DragonPay</module>
        </args>
      </dragonpay>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

This is the button i added to my Sales_Order_View

```
  /* UPDATE INCLUDED BY DRAGONPAY PAYMENT MODULE - START */
/**
 * This button is added for DragonPay for QUERY API button for manual checking of payment result    
 */
if($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'dragonpay'){        
        $message = 'Query the Payment Gateway To Check If Any Payments Made?';
        $url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('dragonpay/adminhtml_admindragonpay/query/',array('order_id'=>$order->getId()));
        $this->addButton('dragonpayapi_query', array(
                'label'     => '[--DRAGONPAY:Get payment status--]',
                'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$url}')",
        ));             
}        
/* UPDATE INCLUDED BY DRAGONPAY PAYMENT MODULE - END *
```

and finally my Adminhtml Controller

```
<?php
    class PixelPlusOne_DragonPay_Adminhtml_AdmindragonpayController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
    {
        public function queryAction(){
            echo "hi";
        }

    }
?>
```

Hoping that anybody could help me and i really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might get more help for this on [the Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: have you written  layout for this ?